# IE7: hasLayout + position: relative + filter = overflow: hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

**Scenario**: In IE7... Div with gradient, flyout menu on hover.

Sounds pretty basic, but throwing that position: relative on the container so I can accurately position the menu conflicts with the filter/hasLayout combination.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WgZhH/2/

Anyone have an elegant CSS solution? I'm sure I can nest the element in another container to separate the conflicting styles, but I have my fingers crossed for a pure-css solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding another wrapper ?
Like http://jsfiddle.net/abTmp/

I've this tested on IE7 (on VM) and it works fine.